# Result of difference moved vertically

Tags: postgis

I have some troubles with understanding result of difference of two geometries.
WKT is in 4326 SRID.

Linestring:

```
LINESTRING (19.607075556663897 52.42680403304405, 19.8499062817179 52.51294623023363)
```

Multipolygon:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((19.659321504584867 52.44578604250274, 19.660323735596357 52.44542952172733, 19.661058574206983 52.44513000512399, 19.66140883893247 52.444997712363474, 19.66193423210677 52.444799271245614, 19.662920961603874 52.44443832883514, 19.662895896239405 52.44441117130315, 19.66255589780094 52.44453504594965, 19.662195671381905 52.444666240710504, 19.661528157839438 52.44490945256342, 19.66134105330685 52.444977530962845, 19.661158108940274 52.44504421808776, 19.660794473116812 52.44518085268778, 19.66032995206332 52.44535553101944, 19.659872126082615 52.44552758700924, 19.65967780561538 52.445600614300275, 19.659357160878997 52.4457211039619, 19.6590540701999 52.44583505081059, 19.65839283348717 52.446083529293496, 19.658183479166333 52.446162225787845, 19.657983208110974 52.44624210355457, 19.657571493380953 52.446406405009704, 19.655854025417813 52.447091645542045, 19.65562885108476 52.44721132278279, 19.655719095417638 52.44720893321838, 19.65578299747952 52.447139283536096, 19.65681575731426 52.44674826586414, 19.657818427094956 52.44636903152435, 19.658223329291754 52.44621588692004, 19.658523032873166 52.446087702720185, 19.659321504584867 52.44578604250274)), ((19.660094169228202 52.44686275393326, 19.660482686966482 52.44719620599145, 19.66042337986721 52.44728918914561, 19.660057581692566 52.44745276102771, 19.66020423399988 52.44771471503742, 19.659791312118852 52.448117282364116, 19.660056246439574 52.44818985162855, 19.660875448742846 52.44853447299274, 19.660913404234147 52.448553777572805, 19.661804697610677 52.4480783350659, 19.662137501262993 52.44799869194041, 19.662258379047156 52.44789804561647, 19.662315354925394 52.44781393331148, 19.662350882710477 52.44769488471123, 19.66234258661991 52.44755601620891, 19.66240763713381 52.447336456203985, 19.6627254188372 52.447257180813466, 19.66325112128676 52.44748162252659, 19.663929282531676 52.44754375352413, 19.664248060437384 52.44752874946657, 19.66471222251856 52.44762396118297, 19.664997778392593 52.4476471384726, 19.665297413996 52.4477155038273, 19.66552946390437 52.447742300288226, 19.66691489173884 52.44793597792838, 19.669631235217217 52.44842495440146, 19.670739501291994 52.44948532607493, 19.671559846548284 52.45024036692919, 19.673722785020182 52.4526347739361, 19.67383808187298 52.45260191256446, 19.673838081884675 52.452601912577386, 19.67505691808879 52.45224490958123, 19.675658608686454 52.45206874361766, 19.676028913260946 52.45196027043033, 19.676216170148525 52.45190205731222, 19.6763394247428 52.45186371004042, 19.675114325528376 52.450699800124426, 19.671832264091588 52.44758127527206, 19.6727398799509 52.447737520042836, 19.672862423335953 52.44777637522946, 19.675796311614608 52.45049927681177, 19.676089575619642 52.45077148052008, 19.676188457370667 52.45080503403332, 19.67626622284957 52.45083143036279, 19.67693983112949 52.4509103328178, 19.677317237833133 52.45094736056685, 19.677817854180976 52.45099655023524, 19.678191811760783 52.45107020756833, 19.67849604893601 52.45119269828393, 19.678589986837103 52.45118017609281, 19.678221477106128 52.45103260986977, 19.677833624277792 52.45095628064825, 19.67723942541974 52.45089795518522, 19.676951495045703 52.45086965788734, 19.67686910777494 52.450860017820986, 19.676289617224906 52.45079205523238, 19.676136998048705 52.45074028382477, 19.67290927276913 52.447744634108496, 19.672764871718233 52.44769888255033, 19.671855647117617 52.44754235026006, 19.671749323479442 52.447512035027316, 19.67072589867985 52.4472206497688, 19.670621604743364 52.44720114191501, 19.670450734541486 52.447145472807435, 19.67011482324035 52.44703599699401, 19.669849405575764 52.44690592172525, 19.669430712917723 52.446717317282214, 19.66909419520401 52.4465939902051, 19.668952587312347 52.44656318544825, 19.668722156646318 52.446521853363436, 19.6676908991451 52.44638908137323, 19.66718101703936 52.4462883327453, 19.666808239290056 52.446201890609544, 19.666643177099463 52.44616362825718, 19.66646240871779 52.44609993229617, 19.66624047810931 52.44607927370973, 19.66580093039485 52.44600232160829, 19.664848134001243 52.445829334762465, 19.664218207907176 52.44574896884563, 19.663497147978795 52.44568599501975, 19.662856408238575 52.445739420790765, 19.662165180045488 52.44590075707892, 19.661579998140848 52.446130160331414, 19.661368843720787 52.44621504378651, 19.661106298448136 52.446325949513586, 19.660484853506023 52.44663025624597, 19.660151739121872 52.446768852460266, 19.659879042675875 52.44690867170801, 19.65944401516512 52.447089882554295, 19.659153720249826 52.44718905464642, 19.658652977893034 52.4473349136858, 19.65848927640041 52.44738267054078, 19.658072875186374 52.447444367503245, 19.65773999942412 52.44747788994646, 19.65726076188732 52.44744359801799, 19.656791349077597 52.44737166612807, 19.65682149725987 52.447391242880315, 19.657281651909877 52.44748706749446, 19.65778508338913 52.44753844149786, 19.65805345693503 52.447502479277624, 19.658513589937336 52.44743453747075, 19.65872642293447 52.44737709151794, 19.659176554902384 52.4472557348702, 19.65946292875128 52.44715975395311, 19.659881545062284 52.44697161606286, 19.659994208089792 52.44690422441317, 19.66009416921566 52.44686275393846, 19.660094169228202 52.44686275393326), (19.67057747895997 52.449252783228026, 19.670577478947596 52.449252783216, 19.66968081140269 52.44838093168002, 19.668275541284356 52.4481370899163, 19.668522972615527 52.44768813961716, 19.668170775832998 52.44745048593515, 19.66796437090948 52.44729527548235, 19.667639153877367 52.447046059915785, 19.667322176348033 52.446806643313565, 19.66699772401824 52.446561569024475, 19.66695697253205 52.44653252784526, 19.666207131740236 52.44669133953529, 19.665720802944946 52.44679442833973, 19.665708427387827 52.44680480466121, 19.665672864528386 52.446813391396994, 19.665302397344544 52.446903494814045, 19.665010094602465 52.446597659506416, 19.66470325376222 52.44627655945323, 19.66430431065789 52.4458590556692, 19.66428420808469 52.44583797647594, 19.66485847917277 52.44591528692861, 19.66489413893523 52.44589861233641, 19.664910385471053 52.445872101407915, 19.665164837014466 52.44591173474005, 19.665618428345002 52.4459911845614, 19.665689538966443 52.44600367133058, 19.666620768947357 52.44623833547406, 19.666720418982358 52.446260490919684, 19.66715124427152 52.44634390250754, 19.667636237746578 52.44642127170904, 19.66821215433688 52.44650298846075, 19.668447170491966 52.44652882394761, 19.668638194896086 52.44655011911105, 19.66905349046187 52.446626787662794, 19.66939817360516 52.44674274669741, 19.67008420382736 52.44706117854674, 19.67053818969292 52.447240560261385, 19.670595585881422 52.44725918147523, 19.670700909484687 52.44729335134738, 19.670775996720646 52.4473057898582, 19.67113217584523 52.44746043146414, 19.671006601029568 52.44751258872664, 19.671192193079097 52.44769011979803, 19.670900612115524 52.44779856379653, 19.671907033743484 52.448797470529676, 19.67057747895997 52.449252783228026), (19.662666071909108 52.446526055191384, 19.66248936664411 52.446561446822756, 19.662489366638102 52.44656144680773, 19.66227344065347 52.446604753356695, 19.66209051314803 52.44619984185334, 19.66121376619651 52.44654620372651, 19.661078761258175 52.44641425940452, 19.66116342207649 52.44637279456457, 19.661422242329238 52.44626346438636, 19.66220845493191 52.4459531972733, 19.662264748203167 52.44594008244647, 19.662666071909108 52.446526055191384), (19.662321782115054 52.445926796208646, 19.662719452166908 52.446516861906886, 19.662950242537867 52.44647327320898, 19.663211626543998 52.446896147417846, 19.66321162653519 52.44689614741937, 19.662950242538123 52.446473273225145, 19.66271945216716 52.446516861923065, 19.66232178210585 52.4459267962108, 19.662321782115054 52.445926796208646)), ((19.660913404234147 52.448553777572805, 19.660803104690675 52.44862560097635, 19.65989353901745 52.449028655321705, 19.65905412603866 52.44981916180814, 19.657558597945567 52.45080714264365, 19.65762953549296 52.45091742165794, 19.666077341896216 52.44877194409817, 19.666119738601452 52.44876118731954, 19.666541776553075 52.448654136228974, 19.666886338948856 52.448004683835734, 19.665498746395755 52.44780468984937, 19.665253677708627 52.44779005994274, 19.66497638718889 52.44771241946302, 19.664647055886597 52.44768236635222, 19.66422934149904 52.44757860116096, 19.663912240372202 52.447586793237846, 19.663233601832655 52.44752097167248, 19.662658194186573 52.44731547174726, 19.662478585655933 52.44735433586036, 19.66240220437556 52.44756433034639, 19.662412853398244 52.44769837193891, 19.6623742949375 52.44782035231563, 19.662311957326036 52.44791150451588, 19.66218228113042 52.44802094947708, 19.66183723943002 52.44811609336243, 19.66095136248388 52.44857299229174, 19.660913404234147 52.448553777572805)), ((19.682182102247022 52.45337009081967, 19.68177667003854 52.4529011640176, 19.681604425707366 52.452703126469565, 19.679899060490644 52.450749711256165, 19.679833839654005 52.450771093631815, 19.679690680383708 52.4508357368343, 19.679343782283564 52.45094430305184, 19.680439357203213 52.45217332430825, 19.68140158550043 52.453268365539095, 19.681749613258216 52.45366430060327, 19.681409199643962 52.453904888581086, 19.681357672315883 52.45394053558951, 19.681149909474676 52.454084273397065, 19.68088130265698 52.45427011495087, 19.68063658049036 52.45443941485242, 19.68036736761667 52.45462569788517, 19.68015903419866 52.45476861868133, 19.67971291836241 52.45507480275735, 19.679252375858624 52.45539089058058, 19.678823592667094 52.45569268102332, 19.678373290682757 52.456020114807664, 19.67807093596366 52.456236491509046, 19.677863902175428 52.45638463584133, 19.677802711026615 52.45642835233133, 19.677705287436623 52.45649790857108, 19.677549295102438 52.45661201933, 19.677296874320632 52.456796775475546, 19.677013768033532 52.45700383751739, 19.676791190779692 52.45715980540474, 19.67567738488778 52.457940077707, 19.67565514180478 52.45795564746491, 19.675357707207738 52.458164073083495, 19.674543697654062 52.45873431778325, 19.67432291655382 52.45888868335574, 19.67436650990659 52.45891182165741, 19.674435379552182 52.45896049942959, 19.674774722074986 52.458733670964, 19.675458562557694 52.45824025217026, 19.67582331217534 52.45802934432217, 19.67584209140599 52.45801643214217, 19.676098342555164 52.45782704821185, 19.676180052878593 52.457766485133476, 19.676335788328814 52.45765138461578, 19.676412661980134 52.457595081471304, 19.676729778058917 52.4573629654329, 19.676878706069118 52.45725398973827, 19.676965481339256 52.45719617917514, 19.677091957032236 52.45710483810445, 19.677422278777268 52.45688841712125, 19.677732752145776 52.45667141379706, 19.67783779830901 52.456597898164325, 19.67809107395467 52.4564139593458, 19.67835969664884 52.45621859701209, 19.67839774442493 52.45619106960358, 19.678418485263784 52.456176471223685, 19.67846990009912 52.45613983555265, 19.678871288019455 52.45585400858789, 19.67892871430713 52.45581312564538, 19.679062084672484 52.455717275633866, 19.67934957463309 52.45551061719601, 19.679361903783512 52.455501766901314, 19.679819795895366 52.45519068233266, 19.68026266510619 52.45488976452997, 19.680483570596703 52.45473970356666, 19.680740170421437 52.45457179479077, 19.681019573614158 52.45437429972434, 19.681256589805336 52.45420680058394, 19.68149706200452 52.45403682287048, 19.682126152329634 52.45425855724657, 19.68231747277998 52.454320548894046, 19.682349810553028 52.45428702454628, 19.682863631693234 52.454447341142526, 19.68321565703404 52.454557139378444, 19.684617103511115 52.45501287546152, 19.685114386648493 52.455151067611375, 19.685868323820817 52.45533651028306, 19.686679959295546 52.455536160667855, 19.687454647913626 52.45572676696692, 19.687909767760335 52.45583868388387, 19.688307425718143 52.45590888677398, 19.688327038156043 52.45591233995588, 19.689433800068997 52.45601898304939, 19.689484994326627 52.456019190817514, 19.690148519474473 52.456084333943345, 19.69019274580623 52.45600204465623, 19.690161302842974 52.456000617870764, 19.68946384346055 52.45596844411685, 19.688639079247718 52.455888117365, 19.688263392556053 52.455836045322215, 19.68793181176839 52.45579003393618, 19.687408653676485 52.455660554514786, 19.68662289816415 52.45546613994309, 19.684935923739015 52.45349188225219, 19.68411288401229 52.452536294474164, 19.683920466868294 52.4523780323353, 19.68354694368847 52.45263443630684, 19.682916730450426 52.45306720080909, 19.68453783855631 52.454927776608585, 19.683168972531334 52.45448965922949, 19.68277281104652 52.45433056461606, 19.681620818886145 52.45399155496376, 19.68160389320649 52.45395730187926, 19.68212297896994 52.45360599535481, 19.682288945154077 52.45348228273099, 19.682667257548395 52.4532384293262, 19.68264720409835 52.45322023001462, 19.682897669306037 52.453045327523206, 19.683916369087143 52.45235264066039, 19.684343049678667 52.45205988635113, 19.684755383150602 52.45180409127007, 19.685178204367553 52.45154176026533, 19.68543170622714 52.45136796476455, 19.685473470144572 52.45133885856939, 19.68579042917076 52.45111876055154, 19.686141931312516 52.45087477794015, 19.6863516013075 52.450735097199676, 19.686640666444053 52.45054245990005, 19.687084611060236 52.45025168509156, 19.687582733271416 52.44992465920586, 19.687845967426416 52.44974449523504, 19.688042824810744 52.44960988237973, 19.687924978936195 52.44949155160749, 19.687647225587362 52.449680183084986, 19.687425471455786 52.449830787188226, 19.687391835756518 52.4498537825854, 19.687229389254348 52.44996396955365, 19.68699291846862 52.45012456589381, 19.686969985441877 52.450138871787864, 19.686509875346637 52.450443937258605, 19.686454350795245 52.45048071051148, 19.68605018399979 52.450754488266696, 19.685707471610854 52.450975019811096, 19.685664726910407 52.451002497353706, 19.685623265590475 52.45103133733994, 19.685320432679802 52.4512414355427, 19.68466263184345 52.45169781059647, 19.68426980965788 52.451970270412794, 19.683883117626067 52.45222446169651, 19.68386691299841 52.452235066923755, 19.683457858477816 52.452503927988175, 19.6834358001117 52.452518422698354, 19.6831335003436 52.452724746331036, 19.682799362326815 52.45295273512118, 19.68272923069032 52.453000578909766, 19.6827594896205 52.4530317446742, 19.68221097302896 52.45340339836788, 19.682182102247022 52.45337009081967)))
```

and the result of `st_difference(g1,g2)` is moved vertically:

```
MULTILINESTRING ((19.607075556663897 52.42680403304405, 19.65986446932722 52.445530464483305), (19.659952341889316 52.44556163655006, 19.66156827170212 52.44613487432525), (19.661662966030175 52.44616846635723, 19.66193007823999 52.446263222210895), (19.662155229900883 52.44634309290586, 19.6626644929678 52.446523749779175), (19.663070459134047 52.44666776292882, 19.663070459146528 52.446667762933245), (19.666470287084064 52.44787382385713, 19.66680689891426 52.44799323412799), (19.66687886843397 52.44801876472161, 19.67057832718395 52.449331117205276), (19.675518189636634 52.45108349267339, 19.68127674365908 52.45312629222447), (19.68228614587617 52.45348436933686, 19.683724904448216 52.453994757075456), (19.686079287417122 52.45482995501806, 19.689222325327968 52.45594492179762), (19.689430093717306 52.45601862592036, 19.8499062817179 52.51294623023363))
```

Here is a preview how does it looks like:
[image: difference result with geometries]

I can't understand why multilinestring is below original linestring.

Comment: The linestring is rather long and has vertices only at the both ends. Shortest lines in EPSG:4326 tends to be curved. Perhaps the difference function finds the intersection points where they are on the curved linestring while your viewer shows the straight line. Test the theory be densifying the linestring to have more vertices.

Comment: I used st_interpolatepoints with st_snap to make a blade for st_split but without success. I also tried to use st_segmentize and it helped a little but it's still noticeably difference which can't be accepted :/

With 2178 SRID it works fine but I can't change code to transform geometries.

Comment: What viewer do you use? What parameter did you use with ST_Segmentize?

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough informations. 
I am using Postgis Geometry Viewer included in PgAdmin.
I tried again ST_Segmentize source line with value `0.001` and using `ST_Difference` gives correct results according to your answer below [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/423514/200538)

Answer (score 1):

OpenJUMP that can only deal with cartesian coordinates shows your original geometries like this:

[image]

Notice that is seems to be exactly where your diff geometry stands. OpenJUMP also draws your original line geometry and the diff line on top of one other without any shift. So the question is why your viewer renders the original line shifted towards north. I suppose that the viewer is clever enough to take the curvature into account. ST_Difference https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html does not seem to support geography data type so I suppose it is doing plain cartesian mathematics.

I would make a new test by densifying the source line first with parameter value `0.001`. Then the result should look rather good with your clever viewer. Add a screen capture if it does not. Or then you can use less clever viewer. The result that you got originally is right if you consider that the coordinates are cartesian, but that may be wrong assumption for your needs.

Comment: So I can assume that the calculations of difference are correct but displayed original line is wrong? Well, this is very problematic for me because after converting line to GeoJSON it is still displayed shifted by using [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/). I must display it unshifted. How can I prevent it? Always segmentize?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a simple question of right or wrong. I would say that they are both right but in different context. One is good for flat earth, another for round one. What you need to do is to keep the whole stack in the same context but it may be difficult. Always segmentize long EPSG:4326 segments is a good rule of thumb but again, how to segmentize? Along a straight line on flat earth of along the shortest path on round earth?

Comment: I don't know if it would be good but I can segmentize coordinates on sql trigger.
 I am new into those stuff so I can't come with conclusion how should I save/fetch data to work around one specific context. I store every geometry in 4326 SRID and mostly transform it to 2178. Length of those geometries can differ, they can be short such as 0.5m or very long like 200km. 
I am displaying on map original line and difference between line and polygons - they differ as you see in my question and that's why I came up with this post. Would changing SRID could help?

Comment: You wrote `Always segmentize long EPSG:4326 segments is a good rule of thumb` but when can I consider geometry is long? When it is 1m, 1km or 10km? 

I need to confirm something: so the source line is curved because it is showed like on round earth but the polygons and result difference is showed on cartesian coordinate? I mixed two coordinate systems? According to this [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/?q=kind%3ACS) I must use Cartesian or Ellipsoidal system depending on my needs?